# Semantic differences of dictionary comprehension vs. regular dictionary creation: Why <dictcomp>.<lambda> behaves differently than <lambda>?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, dictionary-comprehension

Consider the code below:

```
d = {
    **{
        keyword: lambda: print(name)
        for (keyword, name) in [
                ("a", "alice"),
                ("b", "bob"),
        ]
    },
    "c": lambda: print("carol")
}

>>> d["c"]()
"carol"

>>> d["a"]()
"bob"

>>> d["b"]()
"bob"
```

My initial assumption was that a dictionary comprehension should be considered as something that's not practically any different from a syntactic abstraction.

I'm now confused: Why `d["a"]()` does not print "alice"?

My expectation is that `keyword: lambda: print(name)` should create a new lambda function after each iteration of the inner list, and it apparently does:

```
>>> print(d)
{'a': <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7f33d5cb4158>, 'b': <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x7f33d5cb4048>, 'c': <function <lambda> at 0x7f33d4bfad08>}
```

The addresses of the lambda functions created for `'a'` and `'b'` are different (it's also the case that `id(d['a']) != id(d['b'])` and `id` guarantees uniqueness of an object).

I get that internally `dict comprehension` is list an application of `dict` on a list comprehension which itself is based on generator expressions, and that could hint as to why both `d["a"]()` and `d["b"]()` print `"bob"` which is the last one on the list but not `"alice"`, but then shouldn't a generator essentially not create new objects?

Comment: The comprehension here is a red-herring. This would work the same way with an equivalent for-loop. The issue is that Python has lexically scoped closures.

Comment: Thanks! I read the explanation and it makes sense now!

Comment: Yes, read the other duplicate I just linked to with more elaboration.